# Use ROW_NUMBER/OVER/PARTITION to return row with lowest value

Tags: sql-server

I have this sample table

```
TypeId CapId Source Product Term MilesPa Price
1      38423 ALD    CH      2    8000    1404.37
1      38423 NET    CH      2    8000    1824.39
```

I want to return rows with the lowest price for each combination of typeid/capid/source/product/term/milespa.

I tried this but it returns both rows from above both with row number = 1.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY typeid,capid,source,product,term,milespa ORDER BY price ASC) as RowNumber,
TypeId,CapId,Source,Product,Term,MilesPa
FROM BestPriceLookup
```

Thanks!

Comment: as source is different for above two rows,,, it will return both the rows with rownumber =1

Comment: Yes, they have different `source` values and you said you wanted that to be part of the combinations to consider - so they're both the lowest row within the overall combination. So it's unclear how to fix this - should `source` not, in fact, participate in the combinations?

Comment: If you want to partition your table rows using all six fields, `typeid`, `capid`, `source`, `product`, `term` and `milespa`, then your sample data contains *two* separate partitions. This is why you get two records with row number =1.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Source shouldn't be considered in the combination.

Comment: Then simply remove it from the `OVER` clause.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't need source in combination,

```
SELECT Row_number() 
        OVER( 
        partition BY typeid, capid, product, term, milespa 
        ORDER BY price ASC) AS RowNumber, 
    typeid, 
    capid,  
    Source,      
    product, 
    term, 
    milespa 
FROM   bestpricelookup
```